# MYSQL: how to get one row from multiple rows with same column id value

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables: product and productVariation: product variation table contains multiple entries for the same product but with different attributes.

example:
product:
id  name
1    top
2    bottom

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | top |
| 2 | bottom |

productVariation table:

| id | product_id | color_id | size_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 7 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 | 7 |
| 4 | 1 | 7 | 10 |

so for the above tables, when I am querying that data for the products list to display, let's say the user wants data for size_id 7 then we have 3 possibilities (3 different colors) but on the products list page, I just want to show one entry for this product. My question is how can I just get one entry based on the product_id from the product variation table. I already wrote a query that is filtering the data based on color and size but I get multiple entries for the same product, I just want one of these rows.

Thank you! :)

Comment: It depends on what field you want to use as a tiebreaker when you get multiple values for product-color-size combinations. Do you have any other columns on productVariation  table that can be used as a tiebreaker? For example, the timestamp the record got inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing [row_number](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) could be useful here.
If your version of MySql or MariaDB supports it.

```
SELECT product_id, product_name, color_id, size_id
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      pvar.product_id
    , product.name AS product_name
    , pvar.color_id
    , pvar.size_id
    , row_number() over (partition by pvar.product_id order by pvar.id DESC) AS rn
    FROM product AS product
    JOIN productVariation AS pvar
      ON pvar.product_id = product.id
    WHERE pvar.product_id IN (1)
      AND pvar.size_id = 7
) q
WHERE rn = 1
```

Or maybe just `LIMIT` the resultset.

```
SELECT 
  pvar.product_id
, product.name AS product_name
, pvar.color_id
, pvar.size_id
FROM product AS product
JOIN productVariation AS pvar
  ON pvar.product_id = product.id
WHERE pvar.product_id IN (1) 
  AND pvar.size_id = 7
ORDER BY pvar.product_id, pvar.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could aggregate your multiple colors and group by the size, taking the min or max as the one to pick. Doing so in a lateral join would look like

```
select * 
from products p
left join lateral(
  select size_id, max(color_id) color_id
  from productvariations v
  where v.product_id = p.id
  group by size_id
)pv on true
where pv.size_id = 7;
```